# jQuery Mobile Transition Fade

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, css-transitions, transition

When I do a Page Transition with jQuery Mobiles `data-transition="slideup"` the Page itself will fadeOut, and only after that the slideup of the Page will occur.
This behaviour seems to be consistent with jQuery Mobile itself since even the Documentations have the same issue.

I want to disable this fade. I want the new Page to just slide up without any fading happening. This should be possible.
A simple jQuery `slideIn()` perhaps? But I want to do it the proper way, perhaps some one already figured this one out?

*Note: I tried `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` but it seems unrelated to this, since the actual slideup transition is done. Just after the page fades....*

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many discussions on SO on how to do this.

Comment: Tried to create my own transition with -webkit-keyframes but the issue with this is that the first page is pushed up and then the new page slides in as well. I want the actual page to remain where it was and kinda have the new Page overlay without a fade. The new/second page is embedded into the html file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue on my own.

I have two pages `#one` and `#two`. After clicking on a *button* in `#one` page `#two` is supposed to *slideup from the bottom.* Now to prevent a fadeOut of the first page, which jQuery Mobile would usually do before sliding up the second page I created a custom animation like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes dontdoshit {
    from { -webkit-transform: translate(0,0); }
    to { -webkit-transform: translate(0,0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes dontdoshit {
    from { -moz-transform: translate(0,0); }
    to { -moz-transform: translate(0,0); }
}
@keyframes dontdoshit {
    from { transform: translate(0,0); }
    to { transform: translate(0,0); }
}
```

Now I'm making sure this animation is called upon page `#one`, whenever it would otherwise fade away before page `#two` slides up.

```
.slideup.out {
    -webkit-animation-name: dontdoshit;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1ms;
    -moz-animation-name: dontdoshit;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1ms;
    animation-name: dontdoshit;
    animation-duration: 1ms;
}
.slideup.in.reverse {
    -webkit-animation-name: dontdoshit;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1ms;
    -moz-animation-name: dontdoshit;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1ms;
    animation-name: dontdoshit;
    animation-duration: 1ms;
}
```

Finally to prevent jQuery Mobiles Scriptlet of hiding my first page I forced

```
#one {
display: block!important;
z-index: 2;
}
```

and have given page two a higher z-index so it would be on top of page one

```
#two {
z-index: 9999;//this is quite a lot :o
}
```